# Maximum sum from a 2D array-DP

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

Given a 2D array with weights, find the maximum sum of the 2D array with the condition that we can select only one element from a row and the element under the selected element cannot be selected(this condition should hold true for all elements which are selected). Also we can see that sum will contain elements equal to the number of rows.

If arr[i][j] is any selected element then I cannot select arr[i+1][j]. Also from each row only one element can be selected. Example if arr[i][1] is selected arr[i] [2 or 3 or..] cannot be selected

Edit- I tried solving it using DP.
Took a 2D array DP where
DP[i][j]= max(arr[i+1][k] for k=1 to n and k!=j)+ arr[i][j]
Then did this to build the DP matrix and finally looped to calculate the maximum.
But I think complexity is very high when I approach like this. Please help!

Input Matrix-

```
1 2 3 4 
5 6 7 8 
9 1 4 2 
6 3 5 7
```

Output-
27

Comment: That's a nice question. It would be even better if you included what you have so far, according to StackOverflow guidelines

Comment: I tried solving it greedily but clearly it won't help. Because there may be a case that element under the maximum element of the first row maybe so large   that even the whole sum of graph is not that much. Thus couldn't do that. So I thought if I can solve it dynamically. But I am still stuck on how should I store my states. Any hint would be of great help!!!

Comment: @Andreas please help now I have shared my approach!

Comment: @molamk please help now I have shared my approach!

Comment: I think you also need to give some examples of input and output.

Comment: @vivek_23 Done Vivek. Sorry but I only have one test case.

Comment: @ShubhamChaudhary Can you show the path for `27`?

Comment: @vivek_23 4-7-9-7 or 3-8-9-7

Comment: @user3386109 if it's a n*m matrix then, n*m*m is my solution's complexity.

Comment: @ShubhamChaudhary That can be improved to O(nm) time and O(1) space as described by MBo in a comment under vivek's answer.

Comment: @user3386109 Indeed it can be reduced. Got it. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class Solution {
    private static int maximumSum(int[][] mat){
        int rows = mat.length;
        int cols = mat[0].length;
        int[] ans = new int[cols];
        int[] index = new int[cols];
        int max_val = 0;

        for(int i=0;i<cols;++i){
            ans[i] = mat[0][i];
            index[i] = i;
            max_val = Math.max(max_val,ans[i]); // needed for 1 row input
        }

        for(int i=1;i<rows;++i){
            int[] temp  = new int[cols];
            for(int j=0;j<cols;++j){
                temp[j] = ans[j];
                int max_row_index = -1;
                for(int k=0;k<cols;++k){
                    if(k == index[j]) continue;
                    if(max_row_index == -1 || mat[i][k] > mat[i][max_row_index]){
                        max_row_index = k;
                    }
                }
                temp[j] += mat[i][max_row_index];
                index[j] = max_row_index;
                max_val = Math.max(max_val,temp[j]);
            }
            ans = temp;
        }     

        return max_val;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        int[][] arr = {
            {1,2,3,4},
            {5,6,7,8},
            {9,1,4,2},
            {6,3,5,7}
        };

        System.out.println(maximumSum(arr));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
27
```

**Algorithm:**

- Let's adapt a top-down approach here. We go from start to end rows maintaining the answers in our `ans` array.
- Let's workout through your example.

**Case:**

```
{1,2,3,4},
{5,6,7,8},
{9,1,4,2},
{6,3,5,7}
```

- For first row, ans is as is `[1,2,3,4]`.
- For second row, we loop through `[5,6,7,8]` for each `1`,`2`,`3`,`4` skipping underneath columns for each index. For example, for `1`, we skip `5` underneath and take max among all columns and add it to `1`. Same goes for other elements. 
  So, now `ans` array looks like `[9, 10, 11, 11]`.
- Now, we workout for `[9, 10, 11, 11]` with next row `[9,1,4,2]` and so on. For this, we get `[13, 19, 20, 20]` and for this with last row `[6,3,5,7]`, we get `[20, 26, 27, 26]` where `27` is the highest value and the final answer.
- Time Complexity: **O(n<sup>3</sup>)**, Space complexity: **O(m)** where `m` is the number of columns.

**Update #1:**

You can reduce the complexity from **O(n<sup>3</sup>)** to **O(n<sup>2</sup>)** by maintaining 2 max indexes for each row. This would always work since even if index of 1 max is same as the current index `j` of `temp[j]`, the other max index would always provide the maximum value. Thanks to **@MBo** for this suggestion. This I leave as an exercise to the reader.

**Update #2:**

We also need to maintain the indexes of which element was picked in the last row. 
This is necessary to remember since we can judge the path accurately for the current row.

Comment: Thank-you so much Vivek for the solution.

Comment: @vivek_23  You can lower complexity to O(n^2) storing two maximums per current line together with their indexes.

Comment: @MBo Thanks. Updated :)

Comment: @ShubhamChaudhary Glad to help. Added an update as per `MBo's` suggestion.

Comment: @ShubhamChaudhary I apologize for the previous incorrect answer. I have added `index` array as well as we have to maintain the index array of which element was picked previously for each element and then check for underneath condition accordingly. Previously, it gave wrong answer if sample case array was reversed. But, now it's correct.